# Prolog - writing a combination of k numbers in the given list

Tags: prolog, combinations

I am trying to define a function in prolog that takes arguments of the form combination(3,[a,b,c,d],L) , the result returns

```
L=a,b,c
L=a,b,d
L=a,c,d
L=b,c,d
```

My implementation is as follows:

```
combination(K,argList,L):-
unknown(X,argList,Y),
Z is select(X,argList),
length(Z,K),
L is Z,
combination(K,Z,L).

unknown(X,[X|L],L).
unknown(X,[_|L],R) :- unknown(X,L,R).
```

The unknown predicate behaves as follows:
![enter image description here][1]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that comes to mind using your definition of `unknown/3` is:

```
combination(0, _, []) :- 
    !.
combination(N, L, [V|R]) :-
    N > 0,
    NN is N - 1,
    unknown(V, L, Rem),
    combination(NN, Rem, R).

unknown(X,[X|L],L).
unknown(X,[_|L],R) :- 
    unknown(X,L,R).
```

Explanation: the second clause of `combination/3` looks to select an element from the list `L`, which the predicate `unknown/3` does in a linear manner, returning the remainder, `Rem`. Once the number of elements selected out of list `L` exceeds `N`, the base case is triggered (the first clause of `combination/3`) which terminates the branch. Note that the definition of `combination/3` relies on the non-deterministic nature of `unknown/3` which leaves choice-points for selecting alternate list elements.

Comment: Is the solution using backtracking? If not, how can I solve using backtracking?